# How can I use the Woocommerce REST API with plain permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to make requests to the Woocommerce REST API to check the status and update products. My Wordpress install uses plain permalinks, because the frontend is built in React, which renders on the static homepage. Therefore I need all queries to be passed to the homepage, so that my React router can handle the request (If I set permalinks to pretty, the wordpress router will guide any request that's not the homepage and it won't reach the React router).

I'm using ssl and I set up a consumer key and secret. I can make requests successfully if I set permalinks to pretty. However, I need to make queries like this:

https://example.com/?rest_route=/wc/v3/products

I tried passing the consumer secret and key as extra parameters:

https://example.com/?rest_route=/wc/v3/products&consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=xxx

but this doesn't work. I also tried to pass them as headers in my manual curl request in php. I also tried to make the request using curl from the command line. All of these methods work when I use the approach outlined in the documentation using pretty permalinks, but with permalinks to plain they all cause 401 responses stating I'm not authenticated.

Is there any way around this, or do I just need to make custom endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation ([woocommerce.github.io](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#requirements)) says:

> To use the latest version of the REST API you must be using:
>
> ...
>
> **Default permalinks will not work**.

(emphasis theirs)

For the "Legacy API" the following works:

`mywebsite.com/index.php?wc-api-version=1&wc-api-route=/products/1234`

From:

`add_rewrite_rule( '^wc-api/v([1-3]{1})(.*)?', 'index.php?wc-api-version=$matches[1]&wc-api-route=$matches[2]', 'top' );`

in

[class-wc-legacy-api.php:80](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/78e8fb00d2af7ae4a2e3154a4cc7e2d5f4a4e1ae/includes/legacy/class-wc-legacy-api.php#L73)

`WC_Legacy_API::add_endpoint()`

If you wanted, you could register your own rewrite rule and inside it do something like:

```php
$rest_server = rest_get_server();

$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wc/v3/products' );

$response = rest_do_request( $request );

return...
```